# Build fails with Jack compiler + Data Binding

Tags: android-studio, java-8, android-databinding, android-jack-and-jill

I was using Databinding with Rxjava in my app & then decided to migrate from RxJava to RxJava2 with lambda. So I enabled jackOption & source compatibility. Now It fails to compile with following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
  cannot generate view binders java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.NoTypeImpl cannot be cast to com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypeMirrorImpl
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model.TypesImpl.erasure(TypesImpl.java:194)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.annotation.AnnotationClass.erasure(AnnotationClass.java:342)
    at android.databinding.tool.reflection.ModelClass.isObservableField(ModelClass.java:218)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.unwrapAllObservableFieldChildren(Expr.java:876)
    at android.databinding.tool.expr.Expr.getResolvedType(Expr.java:353)
    at android.databinding.tool.BindingTarget.resolveMultiSetters(BindingTarget.java:214)
    at android.databinding.tool.LayoutBinder.<init>(LayoutBinder.java:249)
    at android.databinding.tool.DataBinder.<init>(DataBinder.java:52)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.ensureDataBinder(CompilerChef.java:88)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.sealModels(CompilerChef.java:187)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:184)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:86)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:189)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:174)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:79)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.handleProcessor(RoundDispatcher.java:139)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.RoundDispatcher.round(RoundDispatcher.java:121)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch.BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.processAnnotations(BaseAnnotationProcessorManager.java:159)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.processAnnotations(Compiler.java:915)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:437)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:417)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.performCompilation(JackBatchCompiler.java:219)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1712)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.compile(JackBatchCompiler.java:184)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1073)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:548)
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingJackApis(JackToolchain.java:310)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingApis(JackToolchain.java:189)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convert(JackToolchain.java:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.runJack(JackTransform.java:230)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here's my top level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext{
    supportLibrary = '25.3.1'
    playServices = '9.8.0'
    firebase = playServices
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

& my module's gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        // Java 8
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    // Java 8
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // Support Libraries
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibrary"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibrary"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibrary"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibrary"
    compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$supportLibrary"

    // Rx2
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'

    // SDP - SSP
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.4'

    // Picasso
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // Diagonal Layout
    compile 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.7'

    //Leackcanary
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I tried finding the solution & found some posts in SO regarding **"cannot generate view binders"** but they are not similar with what I am facing.

If I understood correct from my search, data binding is still in experimental mode with Jack so I am not sure if this is actual problem or I am missing something here which could fix this error. One more thing I am wondering is **I did the similar with one another project** where I was using rxJava with databinding & I migrated it like in this project. **It worked without any problem.**

Would appreciate if someone could help me. For time being, I am using `retrolambda`, but I would still like to have it in "native" way.

Comment: `Jack` has been [deprecated](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html) quite some time ago (problems with data binding being one of the reasons). I'd suggest taking a look at the new `desugar` (Android Studio 3.0) toolchain. Here's an overview of its Java 8 [features](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

Comment: @Sartorius Yup I read that `Jack` was not being used by default in Android Studio 3.0 & tried to use that as well, but due to some  other errors, I switched back to AS2.3. But I guess it would better to correct errors in AS3.0 & start using it instead of 2.3. Thanks :)